# how to write unit test to "request" node module with sinon.stub?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, sinon

I have this function in my code :

```
let request = require("request");
let getDrillDownData = function (userId, query, callback) {

query.id = userId;
let urlQuery = buildUrlFromQuery(query);

request.get({
    url: urlQuery,
    json: true
}, function (error, response, data) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        return callback(null, calculateExtraData(data));
    } else if (error) {
        return callback(error, null);
    }
});


};
```

and I wish to write some unit test which verify that when the function is called with correct parameters, it is running OK,
and if there is an error, it did return the error

I wrote this unit test code :

```
describe.only('Server Service Unit Test', function(){
var sinon = require('sinon'),
    rewire = require('rewire');

var reportService;
var reportData = require('./reportData.json');

beforeEach(function(){
    reportService = rewire('../../services/reports.server.service');
});

describe('report methods', function(){
    var reportData;
    var query = { id: "test"};
    var userId = 'testuser';
    var getDrillDownData;

    var request;

    beforeEach(function(){
        getDrillDownData = reportService.__get__('getDrillDownData');
    });

    it ('should get drill down data by userId and query', function(done){
        var getCallback = sinon.stub();

        request = {
            get: sinon.stub().withArgs({
                url: query,
                json: true
            }, getCallback.withArgs("error", {statusCode: 200}, reportData))
        };

        reportService.__set__('request', request);

        getDrillDownData(userId, query, function(err, returnData){
            (err === null).should.eql(true);
            //(getCallback.withArgs(undefined, {statusCode: 200}, reportData).calledOnce).equal(true);
            done();
        });
});
});
```

But I keep getting this error:

Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.

Can someone help? 
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I would stub `request.get()` directly:

```
describe('report methods', function() {

  // Make `request.get()` a Sinon stub.
  beforeEach(function() {
    sinon.stub(request, 'get');
  });

  // Restore the original function.
  afterEach(function() {
    request.get.restore();
  });

  it ('should get drill down data by userId and query', function(done) {
    // See text.
    request.get.yields(null, { statusCode : 200 }, { foo : 'bar' });

    // Call your function.
    getDrillDownData('userId', {}, function(err, data) {
      ...your test cases here...
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Using `request.get.yields()` (which calls the first function argument that Sinon can find in the argument list; in this case, it's the `(error, response, data)` callback that gets passed to `request.get()` in your function) you can tell Sinon which arguments to use to call the callback.

That way, you can check if the callback to `request.get()` handles all arguments properly.

You can use `.withArgs()` too (`request.get.withArgs(...).yields(...)`), although you have to be sure that you're using it correctly; otherwise, if the exact arguments don't match, Sinon will call the original `request.get()` instead of using the stubbed version.

Instead, I prefer using `stub.calledWith()` to check for the correct arguments *after* the call has been made. That integrates much better with Mocha as well, as you can use explicit assertions.

Comment: Thank you! it helped me!